# pull 2 columns from json file into pandas dataframe

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe

```
    {"id": 814984317021495298, "date": "2016-12-30", "time": "18:59:37", "timezone": 
    "-0400", "replies_count": 7708, "username": "im_theantitrump"}
    {"id": 814984316195311616, "date": "2016-12-30", "time": "18:59:37", "timezone": 
    "-0400", "replies_count": 25772, "username": "bishyoucray2"}
```

My json file looks like that. How to create pandas dataframe with "date" and "replies count" without duplicates and in ascending date order?
My current code drops one of the headers names and mixing dates sorting.
df['date'].value_counts()

Comment: What does your expected output look like for these two entries?

Answer (score 1):

Use `json_normalize`:

```
# records = json.load(open('data.json'))
>>> records
[
  {"id": 814984317021495298, "date": "2016-12-30", "time": "18:59:37", "timezone": 
    "-0400", "replies_count": 7708, "username": "im_theantitrump"},
  {"id": 814984316195311616, "date": "2016-12-30", "time": "18:59:37", "timezone": 
    "-0400", "replies_count": 25772, "username": "bishyoucray2"}
]


# Simple extraction of the 2 columns
>>> pd.json_normalize(records)[['date', 'replies_count']]

         date  replies_count
0  2016-12-30           7708
1  2016-12-30          25772


# Without duplicates and ascending sort dates
>>> pd.json_normalize(records)[['date', 'replies_count']] \
      .groupby('date').sum().sort_index(ascending=True)

            replies_count
date
2016-12-30          33480
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pd.read_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) with `lines=True` then select the desired columns:

```
df = pd.read_json('test.json', lines=True)[['date', 'replies_count']]
```

`df`:

```
        date  replies_count
0 2016-12-30           7708
1 2016-12-30          25772
```

`test.json`:

```
 {"id": 814984317021495298, "date": "2016-12-30", "time": "18:59:37", "timezone": "-0400", "replies_count": 7708, "username": "im_theantitrump"}
 {"id": 814984316195311616, "date": "2016-12-30", "time": "18:59:37", "timezone": "-0400", "replies_count": 25772, "username": "bishyoucray2"}
```

Comment: I just learned `json_normalize` that I forget `read_json` :-) lol +1 (and gg for your 15k)

Comment: Thank you... I'm unsure if this is correct since there's the "without duplicates and in ascending date order?" part that this answer doesn't address, but I don't know. Thank you for that as well (likewise congrats on your 5, 6, and 7k)!

Comment: Maybe you can add `.groupby('date').sum().sort_index(ascending=True)`